# Calling a VBA function from Excel, malfunction of "Find"?

Tags: excel, vba

If I call "ValOzone" function from the Sub "test", "Find" works fine and finds the Longitude and Latitude value  but if I call it from cell E8 of Excel "Find" doesn't find anything. What am I doing wrong?

(Exel sheet name is "2020-01-01")

[Image of Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A5DL.jpg)

```
Private Sub test()
    Dim Value As Double
    Value= ValOzono("01/01/2020", -179.5, -89.5)
End Sub


Public Function ValOzone(ByVal Day As String, ByVal Longitude As Double, ByVal Latitude As Double) As Variant
    Dim SDay As String
    Dim SMonth As String
    Dim SYear As String
    SDay = Mid(Day, 1, 2)
    SMonth = Mid(Day, 4, 2)
    SYear = Mid(Day, 7, 4)
    Day = SYear & "-" & SMonth & "-" & SDay
    
    Dim CRow As Range
    Dim CColumn As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Rows(1)
        Set CColumn = .Find(What:=Longitude, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                              MatchCase:=False, _
                              LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Columns(1)
        Set CRow = .Find(What:=Latitude, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                              MatchCase:=False, _
                              LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    End With
    
    If Not CColumn Is Nothing And Not CRow Is Nothing Then
        ValOzone = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Cells(CRow.Row, CColumn.Column)
    Else
        ValOzone = "Null"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: The issue is that when called by sub the `"01/01/2020"` is a string and in the worksheet it is an actual date.  Use `=ValOzone(TEXT(B8,"DD/MM/YYYY");C8;D8)`

Comment: I'd fix it the other way around, i.e. make the function work with an actual `Date` and test it with `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.DateSerial(2020, 1, 1)`. Side note, `Day` is a very confusing name for a `String` that contains a fully formatted `Date` ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner and @ Mathieu Guindon but the problem is not the name of the sheet. If I replaced `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Rows(1)` with `ActiveSheet.Rows(1)`, 
`Find` does not find either Latitude or Longitude. I'll change `Day` for `OzoneDay`, much better

Comment: @Malamare yes it is.  If you stop your code at the `SDay = Mid(Day, 1, 2)` line and look at the value of `Day` you will see it is `"43831"` and not `"01/01/2020"` when it comes from the worksheet. Excel stores dates not as strings but as a double.

Comment: FWIW, your original code works fine for me as long as that sheet exists in the same workbook as the code, but it *may* be a regional settings issue, so I'd agree that using a date parameter makes more sense if your sheets are named as dates.

Comment: Thank you all @Scott Craner @Rory, but if I ignore in `Find` the name of the sheet substituting `ThisWorkbook.Sheets (Day)` by `ActiveSheet` then there should be no region problems, right? but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: put a break in the code and step through the code checking the variables all contain what you would expect and tell us the last line that was highlighted before it errored.

Comment: @Scott Craner no error occurs, only `Find` cannot find the value (although it exists). Anyway I have used `Match` and `Application.Match (Longitude, ThisWorkbook.Sheets (Day) .Range ("A1: MW1"), 0)` and `Application.Match (Latitude, ThisWorkbook.Sheets (Day) .Range ("A1: A181"), 0)` and  works fine. Thanks !!!!